# SwiftUI: How to get notified when a field in a singleton object get changed?

Tags: swift, swiftui, singleton

```swift
class SharedData: ObservableObject {
    static let shared = SharedData()
    @Published var sharedState = SharedState()
}

struct SharedState {
    var allMMS: [MMS] = []
    var typeTrees: [TTMaker] = []
    var sampleInputs: [String: String] = [:]
    var selectedTypeTreeName: String?
    var selectedMMSPathName: String?
    var maps: [String: FunctionalMap] = [:]
    var mapId: String?
    var selectedMenuItem: String? = nil
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var sharedData = SharedData.shared
```

set a file / string on the view:

```swift
SharedData.shared.sharedState.typeTrees.append(ttMaker)
```

I would expect the List in the same would get updated:

```swift
List {
                ForEach(SharedData.shared.sharedState.typeTrees, id: \.self) { tree in
                    Button(action: {
                        SharedData.shared.sharedState.selectedTypeTreeName = tree.newTree.filename
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Text(tree.newTree.filename)
                            Spacer()
                            if tree.newTree.filename == SharedData.shared.sharedState.selectedTypeTreeName {
                                Image(systemName: "checkmark")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Is it any similar oslution than context in React?

Comment: Instead of `ForEach(SharedData.shared...` it should be `ForEach(sharedData...)`

Comment: `sharedData` is not passed down to the view, this is the point with singleton

Comment: You showed the line where it is: `@ObservedObject var sharedData = SharedData.shared`. If that's not in the same file, it should be added to the file where you reference it.

Comment: that is in ContentView, this here below is TypeTreeView

Comment: Does it work if you add it to that view and try the suggestion?

Comment: But I have many views which would use it, I would not pass to each

Comment: You aren't "passing" it to the view -- you're just creating a reference to the singleton and using the property wrapper. The View has no reason to know to update if it doesn't have an `@ObservableObject` property wrapper to watch -- that's the point of the property wrapper -- to signal the `View` to update.

Comment: Why not use SharedData as an @EnvironmentObject?